# Adding a button to account entity homepage's ribbon/command bar

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Playing with the ribbon, I tried to add **a button over the account entity homepage's ribbon/command bar, just before the +New button**. But it is not showing anywhere over the page. What am I missing?

This is the sample XML I've coded after reading the SDK.

```
            <RibbonDiffXml>
            <CustomActions>
                <CustomAction Id="Bee.CustomAction.GoToUrl" Location="Mscrm.HomepageGrid.account.MainTab.Management.Controls._children">
                    <CommandUIDefinition>
                        <Button Id="Bee.HomepageGrid.account.GoToUrl" Command="Bee.CommandDefinition.GoToUrl" LabelText="Go To URL" ToolTipDescription="Description, Go to URL with selected account" ToolTipTitle="Title, Go to URL with selected account" />
                    </CommandUIDefinition>
                </CustomAction>
            </CustomActions>
            <Templates>
                <RibbonTemplates Id="Mscrm.Templates"></RibbonTemplates>
            </Templates>
            <CommandDefinitions>
                <CommandDefinition Id="Bee.CommandDefinition.GoToUrl">
                    <EnableRules>
                        <EnableRule Id="Bee.EnableRule.SelectionCountOne" />
                    </EnableRules>
                    <DisplayRules>
                        <DisplayRule Id="Bee.DisplayRule.AllClients"/>
                    </DisplayRules>
                    <Actions>
                        <Url Address="http://localhost/mysite" PassParams="true"></Url>
                    </Actions>
                </CommandDefinition>
            </CommandDefinitions>
            <RuleDefinitions>
                <TabDisplayRules />
                <DisplayRules>
                    <DisplayRule Id="Bee.DisplayRule.AllClients">
                        <CommandClientTypeRule Type="Modern" />
                        <CommandClientTypeRule Type="Refresh" />
                        <CommandClientTypeRule Type="Legacy" />
                    </DisplayRule>
                </DisplayRules>
                <EnableRules>
                    <EnableRule Id="Bee.EnableRule.SelectionCountOne">
                        <SelectionCountRule Minimum="1" Maximum="1" AppliesTo="SelectedEntity" />
                    </EnableRule>
                </EnableRules>
            </RuleDefinitions>
            <LocLabels />
        </RibbonDiffXml>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just apply one `CommandClientTypeRule` Type="Refresh", it works. Again apply all three types not working. All have different meanings as below.

**Modern**: The command bar is presented using Microsoft Dynamics CRM for tablets.

**Refresh**: The command bar is presented using the updated user interface.

**Legacy**: The ribbon is presented in forms for entities that were not updated or in a list view in Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Microsoft Office Outlook.

```
<DisplayRules>
  <DisplayRule Id="Bee.DisplayRule.AllClients">    
    <CommandClientTypeRule Type="Refresh" />    
  </DisplayRule>
</DisplayRules>
```

But **Go to url** button goes to overflow section means in the drop down hidden menu.

Displaying the button on command bar before **NEW** button apply some sequence, following is RibbonXml that show the button just before **NEW** button, when one record is selected.

```
<RibbonDiffXml>
  <CustomActions>
    <CustomAction Id="Bee.CustomAction.GoToUrl" Location="Mscrm.HomepageGrid.account.MainTab.Management.Controls._children"  Sequence="5">
      <CommandUIDefinition>
        <Button Id="Bee.HomepageGrid.account.GoToUrl"
                LabelText="Go To URL"
                ToolTipDescription="Description, Go to URL with selected account"
                ToolTipTitle="Title, Go to URL with selected account"
                Alt="Go to"
                Command="Bee.CommandDefinition.GoToUrl"
                Sequence="5" 
                TemplateAlias="o1" />
      </CommandUIDefinition>
    </CustomAction>
  </CustomActions>
  <Templates>
    <RibbonTemplates Id="Mscrm.Templates"></RibbonTemplates>
  </Templates>
  <CommandDefinitions>
    <CommandDefinition Id="Bee.CommandDefinition.GoToUrl">
      <EnableRules>
        <EnableRule Id="Bee.EnableRule.SelectionCountOne" />
      </EnableRules>
      <DisplayRules>
        <DisplayRule Id="Bee.DisplayRule.AllClients"/>
      </DisplayRules>
      <Actions>
        <Url Address="http://localhost/mysite" PassParams="true"></Url>
      </Actions>
    </CommandDefinition>
  </CommandDefinitions>
  <RuleDefinitions>
    <TabDisplayRules />
    <DisplayRules>
      <DisplayRule Id="Bee.DisplayRule.AllClients">
        <CommandClientTypeRule Type="Refresh" />
      </DisplayRule>
    </DisplayRules>
    <EnableRules>
      <EnableRule Id="Bee.EnableRule.SelectionCountOne">
        <SelectionCountRule Minimum="1" Maximum="1" AppliesTo="SelectedEntity" />
      </EnableRule>
    </EnableRules>
  </RuleDefinitions>
  <LocLabels/>
</RibbonDiffXml>
```

Comment: you were right. by default multipe rule types in DisplayRule are tied by the AND operator. That's why the rule was not being validated to true. To tie the rule types by OR operator we've to wrap them up in <OrRule></OrRule>. And by the way, to display the button in any type of client we don't have to add any display rule at all.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to try [Ribbon Workbench](http://www.develop1.net/public/page/Ribbon-Workbench-for-Dynamics-CRM-2011.aspx). You don't need to download/extract/modify/pack/import anymore. Everything is done directly from Dynamics CRM and without any knowledge of XML.

Comment: It's good for beginning and understanding the ribbon customization. But still I prefer to code myself. It gives you lot more insights behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

You should add LocLabels to your RibbonDiffXml. Attribute LabelText a.o. must hold references to these localized labels. They are not meant to hold the texts themselves.

Look on CodePlex for some fine ribbon editors; they will give you a good start!

Comment: No it is not an issue. The implementation guide says "**Although Ribbon elements that display text allow for direct entry of text**, it is a best practice to use localized labels to define text displayed in the ribbon".